# Jenkins allow manual build only if another pipeline has built successfully

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I've been having a bit of difficulty finding an answer to this question, although I'm sure it has been answered somewhere.

I want a pipeline to be buildable (not automatically build) only if another step (or steps) has been successfully run. I have a number of jobs stored in a Jenkins folder that are run every few months.

Basically, when it comes time to run these steps, I create a 'copy' of the folder so that all of the builds are reset without any log or prior build information. I'd like to prevent certain steps from being run until a stable build of specified steps has been completed.

Looking at the 'Build blocker' plugin, which is so close to what I need, it only has 'Block build if certain jobs are running'. There are also other functionalities/plugins that allow builds to be triggered once certain steps have a stable build, but I don't want it to be automatic. Basically, I would want something like 'Block build if certain jobs do not have a stable build'. Does a plugin exist that has this functionality?

Again, sorry if this is a repeat of another question, google didn't return an answer to this specific question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the project from pipeline like so:

```
import jenkins.model.*

def job = Jenkins.instance.items.find{ job ->
  job.name == "<jobName>"
}

job.setDisabled(true)
job.setDescription("Please don't start. It is disabled because of ...")
```

If you wanted to start it now, you had to enable it first and would (hopefully) see the changed description first.

Hope this helped :)